# tap image in listbox in windows phone 7

Tags: listbox, windows-phone-7.1

I have a listBox in a win phone 7 app, and a icon image which in every list item.When I tap the icon image, some download work will be processed.If I don't tap the icon, just tap the selected item, page navigation should be executed.And now, when I tap the icon, the page was navigated to another page.If I want to tap the icon to do download work, but not the navigation, can anybody give me some advice? Thanks.

Comment: I have solved this problem. The way which i done is take the icon image to a button node.When I click the button, the button click event was fired, and the selectionChanged event was not fired.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the button you could have associated an event `Tap` with `Image` inside your `item template`. I guess that should have worked too. Never the less great for you.